# Include options in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, relation

Example, i have two tables:
Table Users and table Countries (relation Countries, by one to many, foreign key Country_ID).
I set

```
DataEntities.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

then i want to get list users with country relation
i do that

```
var res = DataEntities.Users.Include(u=>u.Countries).ToList();
return res;
```

The Problem is result list has circular reference`(users->countries->users etc.)`
How i can escape from circular reference? I need that result list contain Users with Countries, but without reference from their countries on users again!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid circular references? Is this a serialization issue?

Comment: Because I do not want drag the extra data for you!

Comment: I feel like you need to normalize your database

Comment: my db consist of two tables, as in Example

Comment: @Mikhail: but you don't getting any extra data from database. If lazy loading is disabled, `Country.Users` contains only users, which had been loaded to context.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question. Really, if i write DataEntities.Users.Include(u=>u.Countries).FirstOrDefault(c=>c.ID == 1); i get only one country only for user with ID  == 1. No cicular reference! Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is possible because with your query, you just include the `Countries` set to your result, and if there is a navigation property in `Countries` named `Users` you will automaticaly get it (because you handle the full `Country` class). Maybe you should consider another way to do this, by changing your architecture...